# How to show that any two equivalence classes of non-zero elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ have the same number of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, equivalence-relations

My question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510659/prove-that-1-less-than-the-number-of-equivalence-classes-divides-p-1-where-p) question I asked last year. I am just getting around to picking up the problem again, and normally, I would just ask a follow-up question to the answer that was given, but the person who wrote it is away from MSE due to medical reasons, and I am in urgent need of an answer.

My original question was:

> Let $p$ be a prime number and $\gcd(p,n)=1$.  Define an equivalence
>   relation on $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ as follows: $x \sim y$ iff $n^{r}x = n^{t}y$ for some $r,t \geq 0$.  Let $m$ be the number of equivalence
>   classes of this equivalence relation.  Prove that $m-1$ is a divisor
>   of $p-1$.

I followed the answerer's advice and showed that $x \sim 0$ iff $x = 0$, and now am working on the next step,which is to show that any two equivalence classes of non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ have the same number of elements, call it $k$.

However, I am not sure how to do this part. Could someone please let me know how I am supposed to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: The answerer was pretty clear: $x\sim y\iff xy^{-1}\in K$, so the class of $y$ is $Ky$, and obviously $|Ky|=|K|$.

Comment: @user26857 so in this case, $|x\langle n \rangle | = |\langle n \rangle|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times$ (discard $0$). Then the equivalence relation can be written, for nonzero elements,
$$
xy^{-1}\in\langle n\rangle
$$
so the equivalence relation is just the one defining the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times\big/\langle n\rangle$. In particular the equivalence classes have the same number of elements. In the whole set $\mathbb{Z}_p$ there's also the class of $0$, with just one element.

Comment: so you mean they're like cosets?

Comment: @JessyCat Exactly: they *are* the cosets.

Comment: and did you get $xy^{-1} \in \langle n \rangle$ from $n^{r}x = n^{t}y$ $\implies$ $x = n^{t-r}y $ $\implies$ $xy^{-1} = n^{t-r}$? But, how does $xy^{-1} = n^{t-r} \implies xy^{-1} \in \langle n \rangle$? Because $\langle n \rangle$ consists of powers of $n$?

Comment: @JessyCat Yes: $n$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: I edited and added something else to the comment I just made.

Comment: @JessyCat Yes, $\langle n\rangle$ denotes the powers of (the residue class of) $n$.

Comment: also what do the cosets in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\times}/\langle n \rangle$ look like? I apologize if I'm asking stupid questions, but I'm really trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @JessyCat Of course they're of the form $x\langle n\rangle$. What else? Do you know the basics of group theory?

Comment: of course. Although I realize it would seem as though I didn't from that question. Like I said, I'm sorry if I'm asking you stupid stuff.